# How to interface an AWS hosted website with Database on EBS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

The startup I'm working for is constructing a website, and we want to use AWS to run and host our site and the accompanying mysql database. Apparently when you terminate an AWS instance, any data stored on it is lost, so we would be keeping the database on the EBS system. The thing I can't figure out, though, is how to interface things running on these two different platforms. How do I tell the web server where the database is?

Sorry if this is a really noob question. Still trying to grasp how this whole cloud service works.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading correct, your DB is on the EBS mounted on the same machine, if that is the case, you have to make sure you tell MySQL (my.cnf) to point it's `datadir` to EBS directory.

Rest is as usual. Your `host` is `localhost` and your user credentials.

BTW, FYI, there is one more option from Amazon for DB that is RDS (http://aws.amazon.com/rds/) which provides lots of functionality + advantages, take a look at it.